# Transform TextMesh in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a text mesh in Unity like this:

```cs
var theText = new GameObject();
var textMesh = theText.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
var meshRenderer = theText.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
textMesh.text = name;
textMesh.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
theText.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
```

The same kind of transformation works on other objects such as a quad. I do not really know which object I should transform, so I tried both `textMesh` and `theText`, also separately.

When I click "Play" in Unity and select the created object in the scene, then the contour of the text is highlighted in orange at the correct position. However, the visible white text is still at (0, 0, 0).

This is not only in scripting; when I create a "3D Object/3D Text" via the Unity UI and drag it around with the mouse, it's the same issue.

[image]

Comment: you never assigned any materials to it

Comment: Do I need to? The text is visible, just at the wrong position.

Comment: The text mesh doc does not say this, but according to the text mesh _pro_ doc, text mesh is legacy -- yet text mesh pro is only experimental/unstable -- what?! https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.textmeshpro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `TextMesh` to `TextMeshPro` (which requires the import `using TMPro;`). TextMeshPro is experimental/unstable at the time of writing, and also the positioning seems to be inconsistent with the positioning of the basic 3D objects, but it's an acceptable solution for me at the moment.

If someone finds a real solution using TextMesh, I'm happy to select their answer as correct!

Comment: Wow the width and height scripting API for text mesh pro is undocumented or missing. Makes it pretty much unusable.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating the text mesh in code? Just go to GameObjects -> UI -> Text or Text Mesh Pro and create it and place it in your scene. If you need to move it just reference

```
 gameObject.transform.position
```

in a script attached to it.

edit: try removing

```
textMesh.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
```

second edit: sorry wasn't paying attention, you just need to change move theText (the game object)

Comment: I need to create 40 of them and also read them from a configuration file, so doing it manually is not an option. But for the sake of debugging I also tried doing it manually, and it did not work either, see picture in the question.

Comment: Gave my answer an edit (and another edit) if you wanna give it a try

Comment: Doesn't work :/ As a workaround I'm using TextMeshPro now, where it works; see my answer. Thanks anyways!

Comment: If your text always feels off keep in mind the transform position will be local to the gameObject the script is attached to. Make sure that the parent gameObject doesn't have an unnecessary scales or rotations.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a color to your text you will be able to see it. Try this code:

```
var theText = new GameObject();
var textMesh = theText.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
var meshRenderer = theText.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
textMesh.text = name;

textMesh.color = Color.red; //THIS IS THE NEW LINE

textMesh.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
theText.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
```

Hope I've helped you.

Comment: That changes the color of the white text to red, but it's still in the wrong place :/